# Is possible to access QQuickXmlListModel from C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to access the `XmlListModel` object which generated from QML. Using
function `findChild<QObject*>(objName)`, could find the object by the name.

I want `get(int index)` XML data like this:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mXML, "get",
            Q_RETURN_ARG(QJSValue, returnedValue),
            Q_ARG(int, index));
```

After referred this [link](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/imports/xmllistmodel/qqmlxmllistmodel_p.h.html), looks like `get` function do not return JS value.
So is there any way to access XmlListModel.

**Update**:

Instead of using `get`, could use `QAbstractListModel::data` to access data like this.

```
mXML->data(mXML->index(0), mXML->roleNames().key("myRoleName"));

QVariant QQuickXmlListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role)
```

If you have any other way please share it.

Comment: That's the simplest way. If you want to get all the roles at once you can iterate over them and return them as a map like I've done here : https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel/blob/9009d1855407019e664932058eb1fe5761ff4bd3/qqmlsortfilterproxymodel.cpp#L231-L239